# Is it okay to use the method of a class as contextmanager?

Tags: python, class, contextmanager

so, here is a simple code:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

class A:
    
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = 1
        return

    @contextmanager
    def a2mode(self):
        self.a = 2
        print(self.a)
        yield
        self.a = 1
        print(self.a)
        return
    
ca = A()
with ca.a2mode() as cm:
    print(ca.a+1)
```

which prints:

```
2
3
1
```

Basically I am using a method of the class to create a context within which the attribute a has a value a=2, instead of its usual value. Based on that some operations are performed that make use of the modified value of a. After operation within that context, the attribute is reset to its original value before the context manager.

Is this ok to do, or can it lead to some unforeseen issues? It works, but I am not sure whether this is "forbidden" code.

Thanks!
Best, JZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine, though if you want to ensure `a` gets reset even if the context-managed block raises, you'll want to use `try: finally:`.

```
    @contextmanager
    def a2mode(self):
        self.a = 2
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self.a = 1
```

Also, if there would be more modes, you'd want to make sure to reset to the previous mode...

```
    @contextmanager
    def a2mode(self):
        old_a = self.a
        self.a = 2
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self.a = old_a
```

Comment: @Barmar No. It's in fact [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to just define `__enter__` and `__exit__` explicitly, as `__exit__` receives any exception raised in the `with` statement as an argument.

```
class A:
    
    def __init__(self): 
        self.a = 1
        return

    def __enter__(self):
        self.a = 2
        print(self.a)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.a = 1
        print(self.a)
        # I don't know the most idiomatic way of checking this...
        if args != (None, None, None):
            exc_type, exc_value, traceback = args
            ...
            # Return a true value to prevent the exception from propagating
```

Comment: Hey, so, I forgot to mention that there would be several modes, as AKX also guessed in the previous comment. In that case, the __enter__ and __exit__ of the class itself would not be sufficient, right?

Comment: Right, you can't parameterize `__enter__`. I saw the comment about modes, but didn't stop to think what exactly you meant by mode.

Comment: Is the context manager supposed to do anything other than change and restore the value of `self.a`? You could do that with `with unittest.mock.patch(ca, 'a', temp_value):`.

Comment: as of now, it also changes the attributes of some other objects stored in the class.